# open several xterm windows from script without closing

Tags: bash, xterm

when I execute this script the terminals are opening and immediately closing, so I can't see the result.

Nothing that I know helps.

I'm using SunOS 5.9 and it's not my fault))

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then 
echo "enter command"
fi

if [ -z "$2" ]; then 
echo "enter command"
fi

if [ -z "$3" ]; then 
echo "enter command"
fi

xterm -e $1 | wait & 

xterm -e $2 | wait & 

xterm -e $3 | wait &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to see what the command produced even if it failed, replace your commands with:

```
xterm -xrm '*hold: true' -e $1 &   # this is to keep xterm from closing
pid1=$!  # this is to save the pid, in case you want to close it
disown   # this is to prevent the finishing shell from closing the xterm
```

Alternatively, if the `xterm` does not support `-xrm` option:

```
CMD="$1" xterm -e $SHELL -c '$SHELL -c "$CMD"; read'
```

The two shells are to protect from syntax errors in the command, to keep the xterm open even in this case.

Comment: Your xterm might be a strange thing which does not support `-xrm`. You may look into pausing the shell, which runs the command. I'll update the answer

Comment: Both parts of the answer have problems (answer uses a feature of xterm not provided with Solaris 9, as well as suggesting an alternate solution which does not actually work).

Comment: @ThomasDickey what part of the alternate solution does not work with Solaris 9?

Comment: It did not work for applications that switch to the alternate screen of xterm.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: hm. As you can see, the alternative solution is very straightforward in what it does. There is a problem with proper quoting of the shell metacharacters in $CMD (which is frankly easier to work around than fix), but aside from that I fail to see what these applications might need which the solution does not provide. And you're not exactly helping with analysis. What exactly does not work?

Answer (score 1):

The `-hold` option was added to XFree86 xterm in 1999 ([patch 116](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_116)).  However, Sun continued to provide the "openwin" binary of xterm until Solaris 11 in 2011 (see the xterm FAQ *[Why can't I use the pageup/pagedown keys?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_pageup)*).  Until that point, Sun provided modern xterm on the freeware CDROM.

The usual recommendation for providing a "hold" feature involved a "read" command after the desired command.  That assumes that the command to be executed runs in a shell.  If one wants to run `vi`, the suggested fix does not work because the alternate screen may be involved.  Also, it relies on having `$SHELL` set (and does not work for some, such as `tcsh` -- but does work for `bash`).

Here is an improved script which solves those problems:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SHELL=/bin/bash
while [ $# != 0 ]
do
    CMD="$1" \
    xterm -xrm '*titeInhibit:true' -e $SHELL -c '$SHELL -c "$CMD"; read'
    shift 1
done
```

All versions of `xterm` support the `-xrm` switch (it comes for free with Xt, the X Toolkit library).

The explicit `titeInhibit` resource addresses a problem with running full-screen applications such as `vi`.  The terminal description provided for *xterm* in Solaris 11 uses the *alternate screen* for full-screen applications.  This is discussed in the xterm FAQ *[Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite)*.  Without the resource setting, if one ran the script to `vi` several files, the screen would be cleared after exiting `vi` and while waiting for the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to close the window.  On other systems where this behavior is not the default, the xterm- or ncurses-sources have been patched to reflect packager's preferences.  Likewise, the terminfo source for Solaris 9 had been patched.  Nonetheless, failing to handle a commonly used behavior of `xterm` would be a problem.

Even with Solaris 9, for example, many users relied on ncurses to provide a workable color terminal description.  Solaris (as noted in the xterm FAQ *[What $TERM should I use?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_terminfo)*) provided `xtermc`, but its function-keys were completely different from the actual xterm, making it a poor choice.  The Sun freeware cdrom's terminfo (from ncurses) was not patched; people using that terminal database got the expected behavior with the alternate screen.